# Setting conn_attrs in MySqlConnection

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I want to set the program name in the connection string. Seems like the way it should be set up is through the `conn_attrs` attribute in the MySql connection string. Here's the code:

```
var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
{
    Server = "myip",
    UserID = "myuser",
    Password = "mypass",
    Database = "mydb",
    SslMode = MySqlSslMode.Required,
    ConnectionTimeout = 30,
    CharacterSet = "utf8mb4",
};

var cs = $"{builder.ConnectionString};conn_attrs=program_name:alireza";
using var conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
using var cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select BookId From Books", conn);
conn.Open();
using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
while(await reader.ReadAsync())
{
    int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
}
```

However, it seems like this is not supported. I'm getting the following error:

```
Option not supported.
Parameter name: conn_attrs
```

I'm using these NuGet packages:

```
MySql.Data Version=8.0.32
MySql.Data.EntityFramework Version=8.0.32
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to set the program name in the connection string.

This is not possible with the MySql.Data package. The alternative NuGet package, [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) (disclaimer: lead author), does support this via the `Application Name` connection string option: https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/#ApplicationName.

Unfortuately, there is no replacement for MySql.Data.EntityFramework that works with MySqlConnector. The only option is [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql), which is EF Core, not Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found out about your NuGet package a couple of hours ago. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-8-0-connection-options.html) the option for setting connection attributes is
`connection-attributes`.

Please make sure that PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA is enabled on your database server, otherwise this option has no effect.

Comment: I tried both `builder.Add("connection-attributes", "program_name:alireza");` and appending it to the connectionstring. None worked. Could you provide a sample? Thanks PS: I also tried "ConnectionAttributes" as the name. Still didn't work.

Comment: `connection-attributes` is listed in the documentation under "Options for X Protocol Only"; this doesn't work with a regular MySQL connection.

Comment: Which is kind of strange, since connection_attributes are supported in normal protocol (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/page_protocol_connection_phase_packets_protocol_handshake_response.html)

Comment: Correct: they're completely supported by the protocol, but MySql.Data doesn't expose any way to set them.